# Carregar applet através de javascript

Tags: javascript, java, applet

Tenho um projeto java web start (um `applet` mais precisamente) e quero 
rodar (exibir a `applet`) com `javascript`.

No Chrome tem uma forma de rodar a applet, mas é necessário clicar no link. Eu  quero uma função (pode ser de `jquery` ou outra tecnologia) que inicialize a applet no navegador automaticamente.

Alguém pode me informar?

Comment: O Chrome não bloqueou isso? Como você está executando isso nele? O Meu aqui nem reconhece mais a versão no site da oracle.

Comment: Sim mas quero que isso funcione de alguma forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não é possível forçar a inicialização,** por favor preste atenção no que vou dizer, o navegador é divido e camadas, basicamente ele possui as seguintes estruturas:

- Motor renderização (DOM e CSS)
- Motor Javascript
- Interfaces abstraídas dos elementos e funcionalidades

Quando um Applet é injetado no DOM isso é passado para a camada responsável por interpretar e localizar um plugin para executa-lo, mas quem decide isto é o navegador, quando chega nesta camada o navegador pode passar a opção para o usuário (no caso o click), se o usuário desejar rodar o applet terá que clicar ou confirmar (variando conforme o navegador).

Entenda uma coisa, plugins sempre podem abrir brechas que podem comprometer a segurança, sendo assim o motivo disto estar bloqueado é algo importante, a segurança do usuário, se pudesse forçar o desbloqueio seria o mesmo que você estar colocando o usuário em risco, coloque-se no lugar dele, imagine navegar e qualquer site infectado conseguir rodar um plugin na sua máquina que pode comprometer seus dados, privacidade (roubo de informação) e segurança, gostaria mesmo que isso fosse possível?

Ok? Então como resolver? Simples deixe o usuário decidir se ele quer ou não rodar, se ele desejar ele mesmo pode liberar os *applets* definitivamente para o seu site, outra coisa supondo que seja um intranet, ou um *dashboard* de um site, você pode solicitar que os seus usuários (supondo que trabalhem na mesma empresa que você ou sejam seus clientes) desbloqueiem manualmente os *applets* para os navegadores deles.

É bem importante notar ([como dito pelo @diegofm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131346/carregar-applet-atrav%C3%A9s-de-javascript#comment273410_131406)) que plugin que rodam sobre o *NPAPI* logo serão desativado pelos navegadores (o Chrome e os baseados em Chromium como Opera já não suportam mais o *NPAPI*), até mesmo o Flash que roda sobre o *PPAPI* (Pepper API) vai ser bloqueado pelo Chrome por padrão (http://www.pcmag.com/news/344483/google-chrome-to-block-flash-by-default).

Eu mesmo bloquei o Flash no meu browser e qualquer outro plugin, até os de players como o do *Windows Media Player*.

Se for um site publico e se preocupa com o futuro dos seus usuários é realmente recomendo que troque de tecnologia, temos *Canvas* (html5) combinado com *Javascript API* e vários frameworks html+css pra construir formulários e páginas inteiras, como por exemplo o [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com) e o [**Material Design**](https://getmdl.io)

Comment: Ótima explicação! Sem contar também que os plugins NPAPI(como o do java) está sendo depreciado "a força" pelos navegadores. É bem provável que a partir de 2017 nenhum dos navegadores mais populares rodem esses plugins mais.

Comment: @diegofm bem lembrado, adicionado com uma nota pra ti :D Obrigado

Comment: :( Mas essa notícia é ruim para mim.

Comment: @gonz sim, o futuro é não depender mais dos applets, flash ou qualquer coisa que pode abrir brechas de segurança ou tornar a máquina dependente de algo (o que muitas vezes é ruim pro usuário). Já faz alguns anos que os desenvolvedores de navegadores vinham planejando se livrar deles e passar a usar somente o navegador, assim facilitando a vida do usuário. Qualquer técnica que inventem pra desbloquear (o que é impossivel pois esta em uma camada diferente) provavelmente seria bloqueada.